# Store password in DB with django

Tags: mysql, django, database, python-3.x, passwords

I am trying to write a little project. As I know I mustn't store passwords in database in their text view. Like I read the best practise is to use hash functions and to store it in text fields in database. So I want to ask. If django have this functionality or I must wrote it by myself.
Thanks for any replies

Comment: This should helps you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django `User` model has the [`set_password(raw_password)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) method which receives a plain text password and returns it encrypted.
You can use it in your view like this:

```
user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
```

Comment: I think It must be answer. I don't know why, but I haven't seem it yet. Thank you